# CMT rollback : how to roll back the transaction

Tags: ejb-3.0

The following code does not help in roll back even if I throw null pointer exception at update() method. Everytime it inserts values into the database if I run the code. Please help me how can I roll back the transaction if null pointer is thrown at update() method. Am I missing something in the code?

```
@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class Bean implements RemoteIF {

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void insertIntoDb() {

        insert();
        update();


    }


    private Integer update() {
val=0;      
try {
            Connection con = DbConn.getConnection();
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            val1 = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tab VALUES('ab')");
            st.close();
            throw new NullPointerException();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return val;
    }

    private Integer insert() {
        int val = 0;

        try {

            Connection con = DbConn.getConnection();
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            val = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tab VALUES('bnm')");
            st.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using JPA? Also refer online tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/ to know more about transaction propagation, rollback etc. in EJB

Answer (score 0):

Couple things that stick out at me as suspect.

- No `@Stateless`, `@Stateful` or `@Singleton` annotation on the `Bean` class.  Unless you've declared the bean in an `ejb-jar.xml` file, then this is not getting recognized as an EJB.  Definitely double check that.
- The `DbConn.getConnection()` looks suspiciously like you might be trying to manage database connections yourself.  If you have any code that uses the `DriverManager` or does  `new FooDataSource()`, then that is definitely the problem.  If you want transaction management to work you have to get all resources from the container via either

  - Injection via a `@Resource DataSource datasource` field in the EJB class
  - JNDI lookup of `java:comp/env/yourDataSource`, where `yourDataSource` is the name of a datasource you configured in the ejb-jar.xml or declared on the bean class via using `@Resource(type=DataSource.class, name="youDataSource")` -- that annotation goes on the class itself rather than a method or field.

See also these answers for some insight as to how transaction management works:

- [How does UserTransaction propagate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118353/how-does-usertransaction-propagate/4139092#4139092)
- [Programming BMT - UserTransaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700628/programming-bmt-usertransaction/8704261#8704261)